# Warum hat das 'V' in 'Vene' nicht einen f-Klang?

Tags: pronunciation

Ich bin ziemlich überrascht davon dass das Wort Vene nicht als "Fe-ne" gesprochen wird. Warum has das 'V' hier eine ungewöhnliche Rolle? Ist es eine besondere Ausnahme oder gibt es mehrere Worte bei denen das 'V' so funktioniert?

Comment: Außerdem: Wo kommt das *i* in *Vene* her? Es gibt keines.

Comment: Du hast Recht, ich habe es korrigiert

Comment: Das ist nicht ungewöhnlich. Es gibt zahlreiche Wörter, die mit wichem V beginnen: Vene, Vase, Vagabund, Vagina, Video, Virus, Vokal, Vulkan, Vakuum, Valium, Vesper, Veteran, Veterinär, verifizieren, vexieren, ...

Answer (score 4):

Das Wort "Vene" leitet sich aus dem lateinischen "vena" ab. In Worten lateinischen Ursprungs wird ein "v" am Silbenanfang grundsätzlich wie "w" ausgesprochen.

Comment: Andere Beispiele für diese Regel: _verifizieren_ (von _verificare_), _vexieren_ (von _vexum_).